# Converting predictions into categorical from pd.get_dummies

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a `train_df[y]` column like-

```
0         neutral or dissatisfied
1         neutral or dissatisfied
2                       satisfied
3         neutral or dissatisfied
4                       satisfied
```

I converted it into one-hot encoding using-

```
y=np.array(pd.get_dummies(train_df[y],drop_first=True))
```

I got-

```
    satisfied
0   0
1   0
2   1
3   0
```

Then I ran a model on it to generate predictions on the train data using

```
y_pred = cross_val_predict(model, X, y,cv=KFold(n_splits=10))
```

y_pred-

```
0   0
1   0
2   1
3   1
```

Now I want this y_pred to be in a categorical format again.
Example-

```
0   neutral or dissatisfied
1   neutral or dissatisfied
2   satisfied
3   satisfied
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(y_pred, columns=y.columns).idxmax(axis=1)` should work methinks. Where `y` is the output of pd.get_dummies`. You should keep a reference to the columns generated.

Comment: Sklearn classifiers natively supports strings values for target variables. Meaning it does the label encoding internally by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could and probably should use a LabelEncoder instead of OneHot Encoding here. You could try something like this :

```
le = LabelEncoder()
y = le.fit_transform(train_df[y])
# Train your model and predict into a variable 'y_pred'
y_pred = le.inverse_transform(y_pred)
```

This should give you your required solution